# unload vs java script - onbeforeunload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onbeforeunload

working on a way go recognize when user exits my website.

ive read some threads on the site aboout methods do to this with ajax calls simulating pings

ive found documantation for unload event that will happen before the browser window will close/redirect

question which metod is better ?

the Java script native - [link](http://chrismckee.co.uk/good-sir-before-you-unload-crossbrowser-javascript-headaches/)

```
window.onbeforeunload
```

or the jQuery - http://api.jquery.com/unload/

```
$(window).unload
```

redarding which will be better in browser compatability and catch more events ?

is it reliable or should i go with the Ping to server method ?

Comment: `$(window).unload` is roughly equivalent to `window.onunload`, so the real question is which has better support - `.onunload` or `.onbeforeunload` ?

Comment: `window.onbeforeunload` is *completely* different than `$(window).unload`.  They serve different purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation within jQuery's API here: http://api.jquery.com/unload/ (as you have listed), I would probably recommend using jQuery's version for the best browser compatibility, they have such an active user community to where if something changes that would break functionality I would think they would fix it in a newer version.